# Nodejs: How to catch an exception from middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, less

I'm using node.js and the "less" compiler middleware:

```
app.configure(function() {
    // ...
    app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }))
    // ...
})
```

Now i've got a faulty `.less`-file, but I can't find any docs on how to get the error message.
The page I receive is this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>[object Object]</title>
    <style>
      /* css stuff */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Connect</h1>

      <h2><em>500</em> [object Object]</h2>
      <ul id="stacktrace"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So that's not helpful. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, ok, got it. The trick is to leave away the development errorHandler

```
app.configure('development', function() {
    // app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

It seems to swallow calls to app.error, so now this works:

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next) {
    sys.puts("APP.ERROR:" + sys.inspect(err));
    next(err);
});
```

This shows the correct error instead of [object Object]

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer, it is indeed correct.