# Catch and trace middleware exceptions (less-middleware) in Express 3.0

Tags: node.js, exception, express, less

First of all, I tried to follow this question (but adapted to Express 3.0):

[Nodejs: How to catch an exception from middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063764/nodejs-how-to-catch-an-exception-from-middleware)

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error('Middleware exception:' + err.stack);
    next(err);
});
```

However, no matter where I put it in my middleware chain, before or after `app.use(lessMiddleware);` (from `require('less-middleware')`) I still get:

```
GET /? 304 44ms
  source : <my path>/style.less
  dest : <my path>/style.css
  read : <my path>/style.less
DEBUG: 

DEBUG: <my path>/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:385
                        throw new(LessError)(e, env);
                              ^

DEBUG: [object Object]

DEBUG: Program node app.js exited with code 1
```

Kind readers, how to solve this problem? I want to:

- Show errror stacktrace
- Show server error page instead of crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my surprise the problem was in less-middleware. I kind of expected it to be a more mature solution. I fixed it and [made a pull request on Github](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware/pull/16). Hope this helps anybody encountering the same problem. Cheers.