# Node AssertionErrors not printing, assertions failing silently

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, assert, assertions

I have a method with the following code:

```
  console.log('Should fail here')
  assert(false)
  console.log('Does this print?')
```

When run inside my app:

1. 'should fail here' prints
2. The AssertionError has no effect. No errors whatsoever are printed to the console.
3. 'Does this print?' does not print. So it looks like the AssertionError ran, but didn't do anything.

I can add the same code to a higher scope and it works as expected, raising an exception.

I can also launch my app with node-inspector and run:

```
debugger;
```

Then type:

```
assert(false)
```

In the same place, and the error will print to the node-inspector:

```
AssertionError: false == true
```

The regular console still remains blank however.

What would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Errors in Express middleware, or, by extension, **anything called from express middleware** fail silently. See [Nodejs: How to catch an exception from middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063764/nodejs-how-to-catch-an-exception-from-middleware) for details.